# Can I use spring liferay for mobile web development

Tags: spring, liferay, liferay-6

Can I use spring liferay for mobile web development?

This is very basic question but I tried on google but I can't find any tutorial on this. Can anyone suggest anything on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can use it I think, since `Spring` is a server side java framework and for mobile web-development I don't think you need to do anything special apart from customizing the look-and-feel of the page which can be done through themes in liferay.

Starting from Liferay 6.1 you can even define [**Mobile Device Rules**](http://www.liferay.com/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/12718570).

For a quick demo of this you can go to [Liferay](http://www.liferay.com/) site, and try to change the window size of the browser and then see how the page changes. Even you can try to view this site in a mobile phone.

Hope this helps.